# Induced homomorphism on Lie algebras and exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

In Hamilton's *Mathematical Gauge Theory* he gives the following theorem:

> Let $\varphi: G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism between Lie groups and $\varphi_*: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{h}$ the induced homomorphism on Lie algebras. Then $$\varphi(\exp{X}) = \exp{(\varphi_*X)} \quad \forall X \in \mathfrak{g}.$$

His proof is the following:

> Consider the curve $\gamma(t) = \varphi(\exp{tx})$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
> $$\gamma(0) = \varphi(e) = e$$ and $$\dot{\gamma}(t) = D_{(\exp{tX})} \varphi \Big( \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=t} \exp{sX}\Big) \\
> = D_{(\exp{tX})} \varphi (X_{(\exp{tX})}) \\
> = D_e(\varphi \circ L_{(\exp{tX})})(X_e) \\
> = D_e(L_{(\varphi(\exp{tX})}) \circ \varphi)(X_e) \\
> = (\varphi_* X)_{\gamma(t)}.$$ Here we used that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism and $X$ left-invariant. We conclude that $\gamma$ is the (unique) integral curve of the left-invariant vector field $\varphi_*X$ through $e\in H$ and therefore $$\exp(\varphi_*X) = \gamma(1) = \varphi(\exp{X}).$$

In his notation, $e$ is the identity element of the Lie group, $D_x$ represents the differential evaluated at $x$, and $L_x$ represents left multiplication by $x$.

I am confused on how he what he does at each step on the string of equalities used in calculating $\dot{\gamma}(t)$. It looks like the first step he uses the chain rule. In the second step he evaluates the inner derivative and uses the fact that $X$ is left-invariant. What does he do for the remaining equalities?

Comment: To be honest, I don't see why the third and fourth lines of the calculation are necessary. It looks like it might be easier to go straight to the last step from the second line. The second line reads: $D\varphi (X_{\mathrm{exp}(tx)})$. This is exactly the pushforward $(\varphi_* X)_{\varphi(\mathrm{exp}(tx))} = (\varphi_*X)_{\gamma(t)}$, essentially just by definition of pushforward.

Comment: @Nick Thank you!